# How to force to save_model to fail when conditions met (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Even when the error message is shown and object is not saved, save_model method says that:

> "The real state "RealState object" was added successfully.".

admin.py

```
class RealStateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = RealState
    can_delete = False
    list_display = ['name', 'country', 'state', 'city', 'acquisition_date', 'acquisition_value']
    inlines         = [Inlines.CurrentValueRealStateAdminInline]

    def save_model(self, request, model, form, change):
        model.owner = Owner.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
        ca = CheckingAccount.objects.get(owner_id=model.owner_id)
        if(model.acquisition_value <= ca.balance):
            if(model.rental_value ==""):
                model.rental_value = None
            super(RealStateAdmin, self).save_model(request, model, form, change)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Insufficient funds in your checking account to make this transaction.");
```

After to validate that CheckingAccount has insufficient funds to buy something, I raise an error (it works OK).
If condition failed => my super is not saved (Expected behavior).
But the green message of save_model still appearing.
any idea?

Comment: please intend your code if I didnot properly

Comment: what about checking this in clean method and raising validationError? because django's message is sent after form.is_valid, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's in [response_add](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1067) in ModelAdmin that these messages are added. If you don't want messages the simplest thing to do is to switch them off as described in the messages [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/).

> you can remove 'django.contrib.messages' from your INSTALLED_APPS, the
>   MessageMiddleware line from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, and the messages
>   context processor from TEMPLATES.

if you want messages to appear else where just clear your messages in your `save_model` method.

> The messages are marked to be cleared when the storage instance is
>   iterated (and cleared when the response is processed).

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
for message in storage:
    do_something_with(message)
```

Same reference as before. And the right way to display the error message would be

```
self.message_user(request, 
  "Insufficient funds in your checking account to make this transaction.",
  messages.SUCCESS)
```

Comment: It's not bad.. But I'm trying to get the form failed. I mean, if the validation I've put in the save_model don't pass, give to user the message and let them in the form.

Comment: My answer gives you that. If you want the validation to fail you need a custom admin form. your solution (with my additions :) ) is easier